# ORA-12899: value too large for column - on export/import, both BYTE semantics, not CHAR

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle DB on one Windows machine and perform an export of all tables + contents using SQL developer 4.0.2.15. File format is plain text SQL, ANSI ISO-8859-1. The line endings are done in UNIX style (1 byte).
The table / column definitions are like:

```
"PRODUCTNAME" VARCHAR2(120 BYTE),
```

When I execute this .sql file on the target Windows machine, tables are created and inserts are done. But some items that have exactly 120 bytes in the PRODUCTNAME (including 1 line feed character) fail to insert on the target machine.
I get:

> ORA-12899: value too large for column "DBNAME"."TABLENAME"."PRODUCTNAME" (actual: 121, maximum: 120)

I don't understand why. I have no 2-byte characters in this particular string, and the export is definitely done using 0x0A as line break character (checked via Notepad++ status line and its HexView Plugin). I use drag&drop to open the .sql file in the target machine's SQL developer (same version). When I copy the productname with its line break into Notepad++ via clipboard, it count's 120 bytes of length.

I do not understand, why in Oracle developer the script counts this 1 extra character.

I have searched for this in google and found topics here on SO among others, but they don't help me or I don't fully understand them.

What do I miss? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary table (say, TEST) having `PRODUCTNAME VARCHAR2(200)`. Import data into it. Check rows that exceed length of 120 characters.

You might need to use the `DUMP` function, such as

```
select dump(productname) from test
```

It'll show you actual length of data stored in that column. Just for example:

```
SQL> select ename, dump(ename) dump_e from emp where rownum = 1;

ENAME      DUMP_E
---------- ----------------------------------------
KING       Typ=1 Len=4: 75,73,78,71
                 -----
                 this!

SQL>
```

**[EDIT: TRIM example]**

```
SQL> with test (id, col) as
  2    (select 1, 'abc'    from dual union
  3     select 2, 'def '   from dual union
  4     select 3, ' ghi  ' from dual
  5    )
  6  select '#' || col       || '#' col,
  7         '#' || trim(col) || '#' new_col
  8  from test
  9  order by id;

COL      NEW_COL
-------- --------
#abc#    #abc#
#def #   #def#
# ghi  # #ghi#

SQL>
```

Comment: This turned out to be helpful, thank you! I can see now that this stupid script executor inserts a white space before line breaking!

Like this:
A B = Len=3: 65, 32, 66 | 
AB = Len=2: 65, 66 | 
A<br>B = Len=4: 65, 32, 10, 66 | 
although I put no space after the A! Can this somehow be worked around?

(I can't format text here in the comments, that's why the "<br>".)

Comment: Try with `TRIM` function; it'll remove any leading or trailing spaces. Have a look at my answer, I edited it and added an example.

Comment: Thing is ... I have a 35MB .sql file that contains thousands of INSERT lines, all generated by the Oracle SQL developer export. They need to be imported into a different machine (production snapshot to development server). It's not possible to "cheat" with some sort of trimming in a sensible amount of time, each time the DB copy is done. I need a repeatable solution without any further manual interference. Maybe a command line importer is the solution that takes the strings as they are, without adding a white space before a line break, because there truely is no white space in the .sql file.

Comment: Maybe it's not the best method anyway, when I need to copy structure and contents of one DB from one server to another ;) I'll see, what I find about exporting on the command line. Whether as a dump or as plain text (.sql), I don't know yet.

Comment: Man, that's just **NOT** the way to do that job. Oracle has a beautiful export / import utilities - **Data Pump** export and import (since, I think, 11g), as well as the **original** exp/imp (which works even today). You should, but **really**, use one of those. Forget about 35MB .SQL file full of INSERT INTO statements. That's ... well, plain wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I came across those exp and imp yesterday and tried them out. In general it works. "expdp" doesn't since it keeps complaining about the DIRECTORY parameter. I have no idea what it expects here. An absolute or relative local path is not accepted. But what is worst on the simpler exp and imp is the fact, that it doesn't delete the target schema. I couldn't figure out the parameters to overwrite the target schema or delete it first. Currently this is still too much manual work in between export and import. But I'm on it :)

Comment: If it was that simple, my grandma would export and import Oracle databases. We ... well, we should **read documentation** and educate ourselves in order to be able to do that. `DIRECTORY` is well explained; you can't blindly type something you *think* it'll work (because it won't). I'd suggest you to take some time, learn what & how data pump (or the original exp/imp) works, and then use it. It's not that complex, really, but it does require some education.